# wordpress widgets will not save

Tags: php, wordpress

I followed this tutorial here to get a "base" theme set up:

http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

Everything has been working great, but now on the last part, styling the "news feed" page I want the sidebar to show up. Everything in the theme, for what I can understand is set up correctly. There are two widget areas defined in the functions.php "primary" and "secondary", the unmodified functions.php and sidebar.php can be viewed here:

http://code.google.com/p/your-wordpress-theme/source/browse/trunk/functions.php
and
http://code.google.com/p/your-wordpress-theme/source/browse/trunk/sidebar.php

So this is what happens, I go into the appearance -> widgets manager in the admin. The primary and secondary widget area show up on the right.

I drag the categories and recent posts widgets to the primary (or secondary it doesnt matter). I click save on each widget for good measure and then if I browse away and come back the widgets are gone. Nothing is saved.

I'm not using any plugins, I have no 3rd party or custom widgets. These are just the default vanilla wordpress widgets.

I have debugging enabled in the config file but I get no output of any error when I save the widget config. I've even checked the page source after updating the widget and there is no hidden errors at the bottom as some have suggested.

If someone cannot tell me how to fix this, is there anyone that can at least tell me how to debug this, or get some sort of error message from this thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

Go to your wp-admin --> and appearance --> widgets

then on the right top you will see a screen options button (a popdown menu) from there `Enable accessibility mode` and try your widgets

Comment: Good try, but after I click "save" in accesibility mode, it comes back to the widgets screen wiih no widgets in either of the content areas.

Comment: your tutorial was Posted on July 6, 2009 by Ian Stewart, that was 3 years before. i suggest check for a latest tutorial. may be some functions are deprecated.

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure I was able to fix it, I just removed one of the widget areas, renamed the id of the primary area to "sidebar" and commented out the "preset" widgets function call from the functions.php file and now everything works. I have no idea but I dont care either.

Comment: I accepted this since the whole "outdated tutorial" situation was probably the case somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- -install debug bar http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/
- enable WP_DEBUG in wp-config
- try to clear cache / use different browser or computer

Comment: I installed the debug bar and enabled queries. I was able to extract the "serialized" string of widget data that is "updating" the database with:

Array
(
    [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array
        (
            [0] => archives-2
            [1] => meta-2
            [2] => search-2
            [3] => categories-2
            [4] => categories-3
            [5] => recent-posts-2
            [6] => recent-posts-3
            [7] => recent-comments-2
        )

    [prime_area] => Array
        (
        )

    [second_area] => Array
        (
        )

    [array_version] => 3
)

Comment: As you can see, all of the widgets are being saved under the "wp_inactive_widgets" area of the array. Also just to make mention that the widgets work fine with the default theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and thought I would add my findings and update this post.  I am currently running version 4.9.8.  I learned that you can not use Camel case as the id.

This line does not work.

```
register_nav_menu( 'newThemeArea', __( 'New Widget Area', 'theme' )
```

This line does work

```
register_nav_menu( 'newthemearea' , __( 'New Widget Area', 'theme' )
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my widget had `input` fields with `type="number"`, and the `min` attributes had **fractions** of numbers -- once I've rounded them up and showed them as ints, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set id of widget like

```
'id' => 'high-light-header',
```

instead of

```
'id' => 'highLightHeader',
```